# Build container with docker-compose, but run /etc/bash with -it option later?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose for **development**. During the process, I often need to build 5 containers (1 for web-server and 4 for postgres, redis, mongo, etc.). The web server container is configured to include links for other containers, it has it's own ENV vars, mounted volumes from development host machine.

The problem is I don't need web container to run server itself. Istead of this I need to exec `/etc/bash` with `-it` options inside web container after all dependent containers are created. Thats why, my dockerfile for web-container ends with:

```
CMD /bin/true
```

Obviously, such container wont be running, so I can't use smth like

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> /bin/bash
```

to "enter" it and run `node app.js` or some other tasks.

Any way to build container with compose as a part of `docker-compose.yml` file, but run /etc/bash with -it option later?

BTW, certainly I can manually start a separate web-container with

```
docker run \
--link postgres
--link ...
-e "NODE_ENV=development" \
-e ... \
...
...
..
```

but it this case I need to append all links, env vars, volumes, etc. as argumets everytime I'm going to develop an app.

Comment: Can you explain more about your use case / workflow? Seems unnecessarily complex?

Answer (score 12):

Looks like `docker-compose run` will become your friend. From the [docker compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/):

> Runs a one-time command against a service. For example, the following command starts the web service and runs bash as its command.
>
> `$ docker-compose run web bash`

The command `docker-compose run <service-name>` also ensures that all required containers (e.g. those providing volumes and links) will be started prior to the container `<service-name>`, if they are not already running.

In case you use any port-mappings, you might consider using `docker-compose run --service-ports <service-name>`. Without that option `docker-compose` will only map ports when using `docker-compose up`.

Like with `docker run` you can also use the `--rm` option to remove containers once you are done with them.

If your image uses `ENTRYPOINT`, you should consider overriding this in your `docker-compose.yml` with `entrypoint: /bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks Jan, but not quite what I need, however I've found a solution. I'll try to post it in a few days.